# grid itemdblclick is failing with Cannot read property 'internalId' of undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs4.1

My issue when double clicking on a row in  my grid, I get the error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'internalId' of undefined
```

Here is my event code :

```
itemdblclick : function (view, record, item, index, eventOptions) {
                            console.log(record);
                            me.unassignedGrid.getStore().add(record);
                            removedDevices.push(record);
                            me.assignedGrid.getStore().remove(record);
                        }
```

When I debugged the code, the error is pointing to : the line in bold: i = 4, but records contains only  4 elements. Strange isn't ? ( the code below is from ext-all-debug.js v 4.1.3)

```
updateIndexes : function(startIndex, endIndex) {
        var ns = this.all.elements,
            records = this.store.getRange(),
            i;

        startIndex = startIndex || 0;
        endIndex = endIndex || ((endIndex === 0) ? 0 : (ns.length - 1));
        for(i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++){
            ns[i].viewIndex = i;
            **ns[i].viewRecordId = records[i].internalId;**
            if (!ns[i].boundView) {
                ns[i].boundView = this.id;
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something but why is it working if I add the following before the add ?

```
me.unassignedGrid.getStore().load();
```

Comment: itemdblclick is of which grid, I see you have unassignedGrid and assignedGrid. Another thing is you have to clone the record then copy the record from one store to another.

Comment: itemdblclick is of the assignedgrid.Why should I clone the record if the two grids's stores have the same model?

Answer (score 0):

every record has an id with it, and when you copy it copies the id too which conflicts the uniqueness between the stores. When you clone you get a new id and works fine with both the stores.You can do

```
Ext.clone (record.copy().data).
```

When you said it works if you add `me.unassignedGrid.getStore().load();` your store is getting reloaded and the records in it gets a new ids, these doesn't conflict with the previous record you have in the itemdblclick.